# Passing data to persistent service

Tags: android

I have a service that is using persistent Notification. He has the method onStartCommand. However, an activity that I needed to pass a parameter from activity to the service. How do I? I need to give a stopService and then a startService (intent)? How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this page -

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

We see the code under "client code that directly accesses the running service".  In this case, "private LocalService mBoundService" - an object called mBoundService from the LocalService class.

You can have a method within LocalService which catches parameters, and uses them however you want.  That's what I do.  Use the Service object (in the web page example, mBoundService) to send parameters to various methods.